# Javascript object automatically sorts

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

```
// mechanics
MECHANICS_ISOLATION : 1,
MECHANICS_NA : 2,
MECHANICS_COMPOUND : 3,

// mechanics
Exercise.mechanics = {};
Exercise.mechanics[Exercise.MECHANICS_COMPOUND] = 'Compound';
Exercise.mechanics[Exercise.MECHANICS_ISOLATION] = 'Isolation';
Exercise.mechanics[Exercise.MECHANICS_NA] = 'N/A';
```

When I loop through `Exercise.mechanics`, the keys come out sorted. How can I get the unsorted keys to loop through?

Thanks!

Comment: What order? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4L8r8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in a hashmap is not reliable. Give you keys an order. For example, put your keys into an array and iterate the keys.

```
var keys = [MECHANICS_ISOLATION, MECHANICS_NA, MECHANICS_COMPOUND];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(Exercise.mechanics[keys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: I keep hearing that, but I have never seen an example of not getting FiFo

Comment: That's depend on the implementations. We should follow the contracts of hashmap. Maybe most of the hashmaps are FIFO, we still shouldn't rely on that since it's not the contract - it may easily break in the future.

Answer (score -1):

What is the order you expect? I get them un-ordered in Fx and IE

```
3:Compound
1:Isolation
2:N/A
```

using this code [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4L8r8/)

```
Exercise = {
// mechanics
MECHANICS_ISOLATION : 1,
MECHANICS_NA : 2,
MECHANICS_COMPOUND : 3,
    }

// mechanics
Exercise.mechanics = {};
Exercise.mechanics[Exercise.MECHANICS_COMPOUND] = 'Compound';
Exercise.mechanics[Exercise.MECHANICS_ISOLATION] = 'Isolation';
Exercise.mechanics[Exercise.MECHANICS_NA] = 'N/A';

for (ex in Exercise.mechanics) document.write("<hr>"+ex+":"+Exercise.mechanics[ex])
```